# Don't want to build docker image for a small code change,

Tags: docker, docker-compose, development-environment

I am trying to find a way speeding up my testing. So my question is is there anyway to prevent rebuilding the docker image every time I make a small change in the code? Let's say I just changed a log line in a big project, then I need to stop the container, remove the container, remove the image and finally rebuild the new image based on the new app build and bring it up just for a log line change! The app itself is big and I am using docker-machine to run it on a remote server so do the math. I have base images and use cache for them but the app itself is big like 50MB. I tried to mount the target folder of my app to the container as follows in the docker-compose file with volume:
[image]

Docker file is this:

[image]

But it does not work. I thought mounting the jar file to the container would solve the problem like each time I just need to build the app with maven and then restart the container (so the container gets restarted with the new build). Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a sample docker-compose file with sensitive info redacted, so we can have more info? One idea for this kind of workflow is to have a docker-compose for dev and one for production. It depends also on the language that we're dealing with.

Comment: I updated the question. I thought mounting the jar file to the container would solve the problem but it does not.

Comment: This is not a Good practice. Always take the build or code change.

Comment: Why to is not a good practice then what is the point of having a dev environment with docker? I assume docker is out there to help otherwise building an image on top of the app build each time is very time consuming.

Comment: I do not have much experience with java, but I think the concept you're looking for could be called "hot-reloading". Could you see if the link helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322488/hot-reload-java-program-running-in-docker

Answer (score 0):

Container images are an approach to packaging to mean *what you package is what you deploy". You can test without container packaging for smaller changes if possible. But if testing has to be based out of a container image then looking at the mount path for jar gives an idea that your docker image building could be spending a lot of downloading the maven artefacts.  Instead of mounting the jar. Mount the .m2 directory to the container for the dev builds.

```yaml
   volumes: 
      - $HOME/.m2:/<set-home-directory>/:rw
```

This could be tricky user permissions over *.m2* directory in the node. A much cleaner solution would be create a separate volume for m2 and then mount  m2 from created container volume to the builder. In this approach, as long as the container volume can be reused.

Comment: The thing is after I mount the jar file, after I rebuild the project with maven and then restart the docker container I don't see the changes.

Comment: Restarting the docker will start fresh.